# Snapshot of object mesh as shaped by armature

Tags: mesh, rigging

I've got an object that I have animated with bones and when it gets to a certain pose I want to smash it using rigid body dynamics.  Is it possible to make a static copy of a mesh while it is deformed by bones?

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I found it. Just like every other modifier :).  To to it, first pose your armature, then go to the WRENCH icon (modifier tab) and select Apply. Presto! Awesome.